# Assigning value to multiindexed pandas dataframe based on mix of integer and labels indexing

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiindexed columns. I want to select on the first level based on the column name, and then return all columns but the last one, and assign a new value to all these elements.

Here's a sample dataframe:

```
In [1]: mydf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(low=1,high=5,size=(4,9)), 
                   columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]))


Out[1]:
    A           B           C
    a   b   c   a   b   c   a   b   c
0   4   1   2   1   4   2   1   1   3
1   4   4   1   2   3   4   2   2   3
2   2   3   4   1   2   1   3   2   3
3   1   3   4   2   3   4   1   5   1
```

If want to be able to assign to this elements for example:

```
In [2]: mydf.loc[:,('A')].iloc[:,:-1]

Out[2]:
    A    
    a   b 
0   4   1 
1   4   4   
2   2   3   
3   1   3
```

If I wanted to modify one column only, I know how to select it properly with a tuple so that the assigning works:

```
In [3]: mydf.loc[:,('A','a')] = 0

In [4]: mydf.loc[:,('A','a')]

Out[4]:

0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
Name: (A, a), dtype: int32
```

So that worked well.

Now the following doesn't work...

```
In [5]: mydf.loc[:,('A')].ix[:,:-1] = 6 - mydf.loc[:,('A')].ix[:,:-1]

In [6]: mydf.loc[:,('A')].iloc[:,:-1] = 6 - mydf.loc[:,('A')].iloc[:,:-1]
```

Sometimes I will, and sometimes I won't, get the warning that a value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. But in both cases it doesn't actually assign.

I've pretty much tried everything I could think, I still can't figure out how to mix both label and integer indexing in order to set the value correctly.
Any idea please?

---

Versions:

- Python 2.7.9
- Pandas 0.16.1

Answer (score 2):

This is not directly supported as `.loc` MUST have labels and NOT positions. In theory `.ix` could support this with mulit-index slicers, but the usual complicates of figuring out what is 'meant' by the user (e.g. is it a label or a position).

```
In [63]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(low=1,high=5,size=(4,9)), 
                   columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]))

In [64]: df
Out[64]: 
   A        B        C      
   a  b  c  a  b  c  a  b  c
0  4  4  4  4  3  2  5  1  4
1  1  2  1  3  2  1  1  4  5
2  3  2  4  4  2  2  3  1  4
3  5  1  1  3  1  1  5  5  5
```

so we compute the indexer for the 'A' block; `np.r_` turns this slice into an actual indexer; then we select the element (e.g. 0 in this case). This feeds into `.iloc`.

```
In [65]: df.iloc[:,np.r_[df.columns.get_loc('A')][0]] = 0

In [66]: df
Out[66]: 
   A        B        C      
   a  b  c  a  b  c  a  b  c
0  0  4  4  4  3  2  5  1  4
1  0  2  1  3  2  1  1  4  5
2  0  2  4  4  2  2  3  1  4
3  0  1  1  3  1  1  5  5  5
```

Comment: I have tried to modify your answer to make it an example about modifying two columns like I asked (for one the `df.loc[:,('A','a')]` works like a charm).

`df.iloc[:,np.r_[df.columns.get_loc('A')][:-1]]` works for the dummy case, but on my actual dataframe it doesn't. I've looked at np.r_ and it produces an entire array of True/False. How do I change the Last True in the list to a False?

Comment: Found it:
`mask = np.r_[df.columns.get_loc('A')]`
 
Change the last occurence of 'True' to 'False

`mask[np.where(mask==True)[0][-1:]] = False`
 
Assign value to these
`df.iloc[:,mask] = 0`

Comment: @Jeff Is this the only way to mix a position and label slice in the same command? Eg. you want to slice rows by position and columns by label?

Comment: yes this is the only way - mixing things like ix just leads to confusion

Comment: @Jeff, would a more idiomatic way be simply (when selecting, not assigning), `df.loc[:, 'label'].iloc[4:, :]`? That is, specifying the column by label, then the row by index?